# Number of firestore databases per firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#service_and_database_declaration mentions one can only have one firestore database per firebase project, namely `default`. Is this still true or can I have > 1 databases per project?

Answer (score 1):

Since you got the information from the Firebase documentation, I see no reason to doubt its accuracy.

If you find any of the documentation to be inaccurate or out of date, please report an issue by clicking <kbd>Send feedback</kbd> at the top right of the page.